# How to execute synchronized code parallelly?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

Suppose I have code below:

```
synchronized(someObject) {
  //do something
}
```

As far as I know, if `someObject` is not final, when it is re-assigned with another value while there is one thread inside synchronized block, it could cause parallel execution.

My question is, besides above situation, is there another way to execute the synchronized code in different threads simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method `doSomething()` is not synchronized, and another thread invoked it directly and not through your `synchronized` statement, then yes, you could have two threads in the same code.

If you need to prevent this, make `doSomething()` synchronized.  If it's not in the same class as the code you show, then you need to prevent it being accessible except through the `synchronized` statement in your example.

If you can guarantee it's not accessible (callable, i.e. private) any other way than through the `synchronized` statement then you're safe unless someone resorts to reflection (and there's no security manager policy set up to prevent it).  With reflection a malicious developer could get around the protection and invoke the method directly.  But you may not need to worry about that, you haven't specified if that is a concern.

Comment: Seems I missed the restriction. What if this `synchronized` block is the only way accessing `doSomething`?

Comment: malicious developer? if he is even more malicious he can also remove synchronized ;-)

Comment: Well, I was thinking of someone using your code as a library without access to the source.

Comment: @JimGarrison You mean, if `doSomething` is a method without synchronization, it could be invoked with reflection; If is is just some normal  code statement, it is guranteed thread-safe?

Comment: Yes, if you don't use reflection to get around the access restrictions, and the method cannot be invoked except through the `synchronized` block, then you are safe.

Comment: And, if `doSomething` is a method with `synchronized`, could it be invoked by refelection without actually aquiring the monitor lock?

Comment: That's really a separate question.  I don't believe it's possible, but I'd have to do some research to answer and I'm signing off for the night.  I suggest you do the research yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will.